# Loop through an IEnumerable and pass them to a model with several if/else condition

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements

I have an `IEnumerable` list of entities like this

```
return entities.Select(g => new Model(
                g.Field1,
                g.Field2,
                g.Field3
));
```

However a requirement change and I need to go through the list and check for a certain string field inside each entity and then pass it to a Model.
If the string field equals a certain string say "a" then it will pass into the model in one way but when the string field equals "b" or "c" or even "d" then it will be passed into the model in a different way accordingly based on the kind of string the field is.

```
return entities.
.GroupBy(x=> x.field =="a")
.Select(g => new Model(
                g.Field1,
                g.Field2,
                g.Field3,

else
.GroupBy(x=> x.field =="b")
.Select(g => new Model(
                g.Field4,
                g.Field5,
                g.Field6,

else
.GroupBy(x=> x.field =="c")
.Select(g => new Model(
                g.Field7,
                g.Field8,
                g.Field9,
);
```

I was thinking of doing a foreach and then a groupBy then if statement. But not sure how to construct to appropriate syntax for that linq statement.
Also is a foreach loop advisable in this scenario if somehow the number of entity can reach up to few hundreds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a switch expression ([new since C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions)). In order to use it with EF, you first have to select an anonymous type containing all needed properties, and load this into memory (with e.g. `ToList()`):

```
return entities.Select(g => new
{
    g.field, g.Field1, g.Field2, g.Field3,
    g.Field4, g.Field5, g.Field6, G.Field7,
    g.Field8, g.Field9
}).ToList().Select(g => g.field switch
{
   "a" => new Model(g.Field1, g.Field2, g.Field3),
   "b" => new Model(g.Field4, g.Field5, g.Field6),
   "c" => new Model(g.Field7, g.Field8, g.Field9)
});
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues here `x.field` does not exist in this scope, and its unlikely that EF will be able to translate this to SQL.

Comment: If EF cannot translate this, one can load all necessary properties into memory and then use Linq2Objects. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I just checked it. In fact, one would get a compiler error "An expression tree may not contain a switch expression". Thanks a lot for the hint.